# JavaScript Recursive Filtering With AND and OR

Tags: javascript, performance, recursion

I am doing the [#JavaScript30](https://javascript30.com/) challenge and challenge 06 is to write a "type ahead" application for searching for cities/states. The basic challenge of filtering based on a simple string was rather trivial, so I wanted to add `AND` and `OR` functionality using `+` and `,`.

I came up with a recursive solution, but when handling the `AND`s I have a feeling that the way I accomplished it is inefficient and has a higher-than-necessary Big O complexity. Below is the code in question, and I will also post a link to a working demo to play around with.

If anyone can show me a more efficient way to do this, or let me know if this is as efficient as it can get, it would be greatly appreciated!

[Working DEMO](http://jsbin.com/timapanave/edit?js,output)

**Function in question**

```
function handleAnds (andArray, citiesArr) {
  // grab last AND condition to work from left to right, recursively
  var lastAnd = andArray.pop().trim();
  var matches = [];
  if (~lastAnd.indexOf(",")){
    // handle OR conditions
    matches = handleOrs(lastAnd.split(","), citiesArr);
  }
  else {
    matches = citiesArr.filter(function (city) {
      return (
        (checkObjectPropertyValue(city, "city", lastAnd) ||
         checkObjectPropertyValue(city, "state", lastAnd))
      );
    });
  }

  if (andArray.length) {
    /* Code In Question */
    var extras = handleAnds(andArray, citiesArr);
    matches = matches.filter(function (elem) {
      return ~extras.indexOf(elem);
    });
    /* /Code In Question */
    return matches; 
  }
  else {
    return matches;
  }
}
```

Comment: I know this is an old question, but it just appeared in the [review queue](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/review/close/123712). Your question has likely not gotten any answers because you're not telling us what the code is supposed to do. When I follow your link to the challenge site, it's not obvious how to get that information either. Questions should stand on themselves, with all required context provided. Hence we're closing this question until it has been provided.